# Live Video Streaming from android device to server

Tags: android, rtmp, http-live-streaming, rtmpd

I need rtmp service url to store my camera video lively from my android devices.
[according to this site](http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/)

I have referred these following sites to implement live streaming at server side.

[Helix server](https://helixcommunity.org/)

[Wowza server](http://www.wowza.com/)

[Adboe Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family.html)

These servers are providing limited time span for free trials.but i need free one.

> At last i found [C++ RTMP Server](http://www.rtmpd.com/resources/)

After working on this server i got to conclusion that the server code was written in C++. So i have added the C++ plugins to the eclipse to run. But i got the following errors

"Launch Failed. Binary Not Found"

To resolve this error i have installed  " MinGW installer", but of no use.

[Please refer this site](http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/)

In this site, we have client code for android to implement live streaming from android device to server. Here the live video will be saved directly on to the server.
Can we generate the service url like **"rtmp://live:live@128.122.151.108:1935/live/test.flv"** using the above C++ server ?
               Please guide me in implementing this.
    Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i install the Ubuntu server 12.04 in my system.

and i used these commands:

12.04 amd64/i386

## install needed stuff

sudo apt-get install g++ subversion cmake make libssl-dev

## fetch the latest repo version

cd /tmp
svn co --username anonymous --password "" https://svn.rtmpd.com/crtmpserver/trunk crtmpserver
cd crtmpserver/builders/cmake/

## build it

./run

and now the crtmpserver is working successfully... for other questions refer this [crtmpserver](http://www.rtmpd.com/)